# Swift Image Memory

Tags: ios, swift, image, memory, memory-management

I am making an app where I am displaying a lot of images, for example a profile image for a player object. I have all the images stored in Media.xcassets, and the images are named after the name of the player object they belong to.

```
playerImage.image = UIImage(named: playerName)
```

I have found that after I've loaded an image, the memory usage goes up permanently, although the image is no longer displayed. It can for example go up 3/4 Mb, while the image file is just around 50kb. Even after I leave a viewController it seems the memory use from the displayed image is still there. (I am using unwind segues, so there isn't stacking of UITransitionViews)

[image: The increases come when I am displaying images that haven't been displayed before]

(The increases in memory use come when I am displaying images that haven't been displayed before)

Eventually the app crashes when the memory reaches around 1GB. Is there any way to fix this, or reduce memory use?

Comment: Did it worked for you? If it did, it would be great to accept answer so future users can know it.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem just last week. What I did is to change all:

```
UIImage named
```

to:

```
UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile
```

The memory allocated with the first method seems not to be released by the Garbage collector, whereas the memory allocated with the second one yes.

---

Im not a swift master, but I think this will work:

```
UIImage(contentsOfFile: (Bundle.main .path(forResource: "imageName", ofType: "png"))!);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how would I write that in swift?